# How To Debug WPF DataGrid Appearance Differences In Deployment?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have created a WPF application which uses many DataGrid controls on different tabs in the user interface.  I applied a date format to selected date columns with this code:

oColumn.Binding.StringFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";

I also set some columns as hidden with this code:

oColumn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;

Those both work perfectly on my machine running both in Visual Studio and from an exe.  However, I gave a copy of the exe to someone else in the company here running on a different machine.  The date columns are not formatted correctly and the hidden columns are visible on her machine.  Also some of her columns don't sort when she clicks their header, but they sort correctly on my machine.

We tried to solve this by creating a setup project and including .NET 4.5 in the setup.  She ran the setup and the problems continued unchanged.  We tried setting compatibility mode to Windows 7 on her machine and the problems continued unchanged.  Can anyone suggest how we correct this in production so that the user will see the DataGrid columns correctly formatted and sorting?

Comment: What's her operating system? Can you include a picture of how it looks on your computer vs on her computer?

Comment: It turns out her operating system is Windows 7 Professional.  It won't be quick to get the images of both screens on here and I don't see how that's going to be the difference between getting a solution and not getting a solution.  On her screen the date columns display dates like "09/30/2015 12:00:00 AM" and on my screen they display correctly as "09/30/2015".  There are also some extra columns to the right that are correctly hidden on my screen.